# Pandas Count Positive/Negative/Neutral Values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, pandas-groupby

In Python Pandas, I have a data frame with columns and records in the following format:

```
text           source    senti
-------------------------------
great food     site1     0.6
awful staff    site4     -0.4
good chef      site8     0.4
average food   site6     0.05
bad food       site2     -0.8
```

The text column is essentially  a description or opinion of something. I want to draw some conclusions about average sentiment on the sets of data, with the output like this.

```
sentiment    count
----------------
positive     2
neutral      1
negative     2
```

Where we have a count of 'senti' grouped as positive, negative or neutral.

The sentiments are counted as each group upon meeting the following conditions:

- A positive record has sentiment >0.1
- Neutral records have scores >-0.1 AND <0.1
- Negative records have scores <-0.1

Big thanks in advance

Comment: use `pandas.qcut` with custom bins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `pd.cut` + `groupby`

```
cut = pd.cut(
    df.senti,
    [-np.inf, -.1, .1, np.inf],
    labels=['positive', 'neutral', 'negative']
)

df.groupby(cut).senti.count().reset_index(name='count')

      senti  count
0  positive      2
1   neutral      1
2  negative      2
```

---

As pointed out by @root, `pd.value_counts` gives the same solution on the `cut` variable.

```
pd.value_counts(cut, sort=False).rename_axis('senti').reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: Using `value_counts` should be give the same results but be a bit faster than doing a `groupby`, i.e. `pd.cut(...).value_counts()`.

Comment: the positive and negative were the wrong way around, but it works!

Comment: @LewisAnderson whoops :-) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Another version which uses `apply` to map to the groups:

```
df.groupby(df['senti'].apply(lambda x: 'negative' if x < -0.1 else 'positive' if x > 0.1 else 'neutral'))['senti'].count()
```

Comment: Instead of ... `['senti'].count()`, using just `.size()` seems like a cleaner solution.