# get count of all positive values at each row - pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have dataset with values above and below 0 and I want to calculate count of +ve and -ve with sum and count of values above a threshold added as new column. This dataset has 60 columns.

Dataset

```
A  B       C  D  E
0  foo   1.2 -1  2
1  bar   1.3 -2 -4
2  baz   2.1  2  5
```

The desired result,

```
A  B         C  D  E    postive_count   negative_count sum_pos   sum_neg    above_2
0  foo     1.2 -1  2                2               1      3.2        -1          1
1  bar     1.3 -2 -4                1               2      1.3        -6          0
2  baz     2.1  2  5                3               3      9.1         0          3
```

I have tried [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276598/get-count-of-all-positive-values-from-a-the-last-150-rows-at-each-row-pandas) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907842/pandas-count-positive-negative-neutral-values) but these add it for columns and not full row. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use axis to apply the operation row-wise:
`df['positive_count'] = df[df>0].count(axis=1)`